# How to detects and perform actions on image in Android

Tags: android

[image]

Please see above image. My requirement is I should able to detect whether on which number I have clicked. This is single image.

Comment: please post some code and explain a bit more

Comment: I dont have no ideas.. plz suggest some ideas to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

use transparent textviews and place them above the numbers and implement their actionlistenerr. But you have to tackle multiple screens resolutions.